# date format like 'jan 2010'

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hi in my table i am saving the date as '2010-12-01' i,e but i want to convert the above date as 'Dec 2010'..can u please suggest me how to convert it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or in MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-01-12', '%M %Y')
```

Updated for "Jan 2011":

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-01-12', '%b %Y')
```

Comment: @predrag.music:Thank u so much

Comment: Hi predrag.music: i am having the result like                               final                                                                      75                                                                     80                                                                   this is my final output of my query,,here the problem i am gettin is iwant to sum the final amount like i should get it as                    final                                                                       155

Comment: select sum(AdvRcptAmt)as sum from tbl_advancereceipt
where idAdvanceallot=28

union

SELECT sum(emicalc) as sum
   FROM tbl_emirecoverable
   where idrecovery BETWEEN

                           (select min(IdRecovery)
                           from tbl_emirecoverable
                           where idAdvanceallot=28)

                        and

                          (Select (IdRecovery)
                       from tbl_emirecoverable
                           where month in (SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-06-12', '%b %Y') as month)
                           and idAdvanceallot=28)

Comment: @predrag.music:sir,,i am getting my final output with column name as sum and it contains two rows of numbers now i want to add those numbers sir

Comment: @predrag.music:select sum(AdvRcptAmt)as sum from tbl_advancereceipt where idAdvanceallot=28 union SELECT sum(emicalc) as sum FROM tbl_emirecoverable where idrecovery BETWEEN (select min(IdRecovery) from tbl_emirecoverable where idAdvanceallot=28) and (Select (IdRecovery) from tbl_emirecoverable where month in (SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-06-12', '%b %Y') as month) and idAdvanceallot=28)

Comment: If i understand You correctly U must get sum of your 2 union selects. From first You get75 and from second You get 80. And You want a sum of those results. Is this correct?

Comment: @predrag.music:see i am having query like                                               select ........                                                        union                                                                    select.........now i got the result in two rows but i want to add those two rows and display it in single row

Comment: You could separete selects and store each to $sum1 and $sum2. And in php just $sum=$sum1+$sum2; I have to go now. tell me if it is working and later i'll answer you.

Comment: but the main problem is still i want to do some manipulation with the result data,,,like i want to substract the result data

Comment: Well this works for me and i even formated the number for you on 2 decimals:): SET @total = 0;

select FORMAT((@total:=@total + sum(AdvRcptAmt)), 2) as sum
from tbl_advancereceipt 
where idAdvanceallot=28 
union 
SELECT  FORMAT((@total:=@total + sum(emicalc)), 2) as sum
FROM tbl_emirecoverable 
where idrecovery 
BETWEEN (select min(IdRecovery) from tbl_emirecoverable where idAdvanceallot=28) 
and 
(Select (IdRecovery) from tbl_emirecoverable where month in (SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-06-12', '%b %Y') as month) and idAdvanceallot=28);

Comment: @predrag.mustic:i am using the previous method as u told na,,like taking it into two different variables and adding it $sum=$sum1+$sum2  thank u

Comment: @predrg.music;yeah i got the result

Comment: @predrg.music:Hi i have posted one question can u please get me the solution ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using php then do the following:

```
echo date("M Y", strtotime("2010-12-01"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, if you want to use a different language for phps date function, you can use

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, "da_DK");
```

to set it to danish (or any other language) instead of making a service function to parse this.